# Illustrator: Font thickness letter 'I' changes when exporting

Tags: adobe-illustrator, fonts, export

I am exporting a logo in a certain font.
When editing in Illustrator all is well.
When exporting the capital letter I is thicker than the other letters.

Because the letter I is perfect slim rectangle in comparison to the others. 
How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Fonts have a technology called hinting that takes care of the very small sizes aliasing differently. Now for understandable but not immediately obvious reasons:

- If you expand the font then it will no longer hint.
- If you export a image with art optimized anti aliasing it will not hint.

And then the display software may bug out and not hint even if its a font, not much you can do about that. Finally if you rely on browser to downscale the image it will not hint also.

Answer (score 1):

If you export to bitmap (PNG, JPG etc...) in low resolution, this may happen. Export in larger pixel dimensions or use larger font size. Probably some other parts suffer as well.

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen to a PDF export when viewed in Acrobat. Its a screen preview issue and shouldn't happen when printing. Nothing you can do to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue when printing to PDF, thicker i's than rest of text. The issue was solved when I used "Edit > Save a Copy" then chose PDF filetype.