# PDF files of logos are rendering different on my system

Tags: logo, pdf, shapes, adobe-acrobat

Problem: the "I" in Advisors, Analysis and the 1st Bracket separating the two words are more prominent than the other characters in the Logo on my system than what is produced by a professional Graphics Designer.

Why would my computer using an AMD Radeon Pro W5700 GPU, with an AMD Ryzen 9 5950X CPU, ROG Crosshair VIII Hero Motherboard, and finally (I hope) Acer XF240H Monitors. Screen shots of specs and properties below. Any help or guidance is appreciated. Tweaking of settings possibly, or is this expected or unusual in PDF files.

[image: PDF Document Properties]

[image: Logo Tag Line with rendering conflicts]

[image: Monitor settings]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Illustrator: Font thickness letter 'I' changes when exporting](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/87336/illustrator-font-thickness-letter-i-changes-when-exporting) or this: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/99668/the-logo-i-have-made-in-illustrator-changes-when-i-save-to-pdf

Comment: As suggested in the linked posts outlining (or expanding to fill if it contains strokes) may help. This it is  best practice anyhow for logo files, for different reasons.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem with PDF displaying letter I. If you zoom in you will see that the lines are all of the same thickness.

Answer (score 0):

The hardware specs are irrelevant, this will happen on any computer and its a common display issue, not affecting print work.

However, there is a "hack" for this:

- You can edit your logo in Illustrator, and add some random anchor points to break the vertical edges of an "I". This creates additional vertical segments and for some reason fixes the issue.
- Resave as AI and/or PDF.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for answering this Lucian, and thanks for the hack/work around.